# Java process stay in running state and consume CPU

Tags: ubuntu, java, process, cpu-usage, memory-usage

I have a jar running in background on a Ubuntu server.

In a certain moment, the application start consumming too much CPU (400%) and 4 child process stay in R state:

[image: HTOP state before/after problem]

N.B: the problem is generating NOT because of an amount of using, it is caused just after a certain time (3-4 days). We have to kill java and re-run it.

**EDIT ADD GC Log:**

I did java -verbose:gc and here is what I got between restarting the app and when the application show the problem explained before.

[image: Graph Line of the GC]

Comment: This is a question for stack overflow.

Comment: @Tim The reason I wrote the question here, is because I think the problem become from a configuration of jvm or memory issue or something like that. Because if there was a problem in the developement side, the app won't work for 3 days correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for a java process to run away is if it encounters memory pressure and spends most of its time garbage collecting.  Run the process with -verbose:gc and you'll see it running a gc in a tight cycle when it experiences the high CPU.

Answer (score -1):

Your Java application has some issue which makes it do that. You should study your application's logs to find out the reason and ask the application's developer to fix it.